# Square Wave Generator Problem

Tags: signal, ltspice

I was aiming to make a square wave generator which gives 16 kHz -7V,+7V square wave signal. I have used [this design](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Electronic/square.html#c3) however i could not reach a clear square wave. I have shown the LTSpice simulation result and circuit below. If you have any idea, i will be happy. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: eeek 741.. see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp

Comment: A "clear square wave" is not physical. There is always some rise and fall times.

Comment: What is the slewrate of a 741?

Comment: 10v slew in 20uS, that sounds about right for a 741

Comment: What I find funny about this is that *if* one wanted to calculate the required slew rate for an opamp, given the desire to generate a sine wave output and a frequency of \$16\:\textrm{kHz}\$ then one would actually *calculate* the need for at least \$\frac{0.5\:\textrm{V}}{\mu\textrm{s}}\$. Which, mysteriously and entirely coincidentally, happens to be the rate of a 741. Hmm.

Comment: Use a real opamp symbols for opamps in schematics.  There is a reason they exist.

Comment: A CD4106 run as an RC relaxation oscillator will make your life easier.